# UDP processing with UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter to create a pub-sub channel

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have to receive UDP  in a channel and pipe to 2 subscription channels. For that I have 2 Serviceactivator function with the same input channel.

```
@Autowired
private PublishSubscribeChannel channel;

@Bean
public UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter udpIn() {
   final UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new 
                      UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter(<port>);
   adapter.setPoolSize(6);
   adapter.setOutputChannel(channel); //Is it required?
   adapter.setOutputChannelName("udpInboundChannel");
   adapter.stop();
   return adapter;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "udpInboundChannel")
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
  ----
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "udpInboundChannel")
    public void handleMessageDifferently(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
  ---
}
```

My question, do I need to set the channel `adapter.setOutputChannel(channel)` like this? Or `UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter`  provides a pub-sub channel by default as I needed ?

Comment: You don't need to provide a channel **and** a channel name - one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your configuration the `udpInboundChannel` is DirectChannel. If you want it to be PubSub channel simply declare a new bean

```
 @Bean
 public MessageChannel udpInboundChannel() {
      return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
 }
```

Comment: Did you notice, I have `@autowired` the `PublishSubscribeChannel` ?

Comment: You don't need to provide a channel **and** a channel name - one or the other; the channel will be resolved from its name when the first message is received.

Comment: I did, but I don't see where it is created or how it's named. Calling `setOutputChannel` and then `setOutputChannelName` is kind of redundant. Usually it's one or the other, otherwise you may be actually pointing to two different channels.

Comment: If you set both (and they are different), the `channelName` property wins in this case - setting a name tells the framework you want it to be resolved.